# OpenCV with CUDA on Ubuntu 14.04 installation error

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, cuda, opencv

When I try to install opencv with CUDA 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 it returns the same error message.

I'm running cmake with the following command

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 ..
```

But it always returns this error

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/luss/git/opencv/modules/cudacodec
```

It does recognize the CUDA version but something goes wrong with linking it or something.

Here the full log of the cmake:

```
-- Detected version of GNU GCC: 48 (408)
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.8", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found OpenEXR: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-base-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-base-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-video-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-video-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-app-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-app-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-riff-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-riff-1.0' not found
-- checking for module 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0'
--   package 'gstreamer-pbutils-1.0' not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h - found
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h
-- Looking for sys/videoio.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libavresample'
--   package 'libavresample' not found
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h
-- Looking for libavformat/avformat.h - found
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h
-- Looking for ffmpeg/avformat.h - not found
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- found IPP (ICV version): 8.2.1 [8.2.1]
-- at: /home/luss/git/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 7.0
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_21;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=compute_30
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found suitable exact version "2.7.6")
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4.3", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (Required is exact version "3.4.3")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.0.0-dev =====================================
--   Version control:               3.0.0-271-g09b9b0f
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Host:                        Linux 3.13.0-61-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               RELEASE
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 4.8.4)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffast-math -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Test Qt5::Concurrent Qt5::OpenGL /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so gstvideo-0.10 gstapp-0.10 gstbase-0.10 gstriff-0.10 gstpbutils-0.10 gstreamer-0.10 gobject-2.0 gmodule-2.0 gthread-2.0 xml2 glib-2.0 dc1394 v4l1 v4l2 avcodec avformat avutil swscale dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so tbb cudart nppc nppi npps cublas cufft
--     3rdparty dependencies:       libwebp ippicv
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 cudev hal core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo stitching superres videostab
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 java python2 python3 viz
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT 5.x:                      YES (ver 5.2.1)
--     QT OpenGL support:           YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.2.1)
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        build (ver 0.3.1)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       codec:                     YES (ver 54.35.0)
--       format:                    YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       util:                      YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       resample:                  NO
--       gentoo-style:              YES
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    Using libv4l1 (ver 1.0.1) / libv4l2 (ver 1.0.1)
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            TBB (ver 4.2 interface 7000)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     8.2.1 [8.2.1]
--          at:                     /home/luss/git/opencv/3rdparty/ippicv/unpack/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use Eigen:                   NO
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 7.0)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  YES
--     USE NVCUVID:                 YES
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 21 30 35
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:            30
--     Use fast math:               YES
-- 
--   OpenCL:
--     Version:                     dynamic
--     Include path:                /home/luss/git/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   NO
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         NO
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     NO
--     PlantUML:                    NO
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              YES
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/luss/git/opencv/release
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
CUDA_nvcuvid_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "opencv_cudacodec" in directory /home/luss/git/opencv/modules/cudacodec

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/luss/git/opencv/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/luss/git/opencv/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Anyone had a similar problem or any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try finding a solution to this - ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_MEX_SCRIPT MATLAB_INCLUDE_DIRS MATLAB_ROOT_DIR MATLAB_LIBRARIES MATLAB_LIBRARY_DIRS MATLAB_MEXEXT MATLAB_ARCH MATLAB_BIN) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file

Comment: I installed `python3-numpy` and `libvtk6-dev` to get rid of the ImportError and the VTK not found (Not it says VTK disabled because of possbiel incompatible combination: OpenCV+Qt5, and VTK ver.6.0.0 with Qt4). Matlab I can't install, but I don't think it is necessary, is it? The cmake error in the end didn't change,so it hadn't had any influence on that

Comment: Just found a solution to get rid of the cmake error. I had to link `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libnvcuvid.so /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so` and `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libnvcuvid.so.1 /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so.1`. Now the error seems solved. I'll see if the video codec really is running when it is installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing `libnvcuvid` library which could be solved with the following links

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libnvcuvid.so /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-346/libnvcuvid.so.1 /usr/lib/libnvcuvid.so.1
```

This solves the cmake error and afterwards allows to use the cuda video codec with opencv.

Comment: If you're still around here, please accept your answer =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was also looking for such complete installation process,

I have followed these two tutorials, there are two playlists, one for OpenCV and then for CUDA installation with OpenCV configuration.

I would suggest you to remove everything, cuda and openCV, and start from the scratch. Do first OpenCV installation and then CUDA.
 It would work.

1) OpenCV: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1lqxOwNjObyZ_hngOFPrYsSy-ThwQPg

**NOTE: You may not have to install from Video 2 and 3.**

2) CUDA + OpenCV config.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1lqxOwNjOZbnF_m2g2ZQl3Y0F_NJqvM